# find the intersection of elements of powerset one by one

Tags: algorithm, performance, set, intersection, discrete-mathematics

```
Let S = { trigon, tetragon , pentagon , ... ,... } is a set of polygons
```

How to calculate intersection of subsets of (every element actually) `Powerset(S)`

```
Powerset(S) =[ {} , {trigon} , {tetragon} , {pentagon} , {trigon, tetragon} , {trigon,pentagon} ,......]

for i in Powerset(S)
  find intersect(i)
```

I need really fast algorithm, is there any solution?
intersection funtion is so expansive and therefore I want minimize this

Are dynamic programming solutions suitable for this?

[image]

Comment: The powerset of S is the set of all subsets of S. It is not the intersection of all subsets of S. The intersection of all subsets is always empty.

Comment: Are you looking to write the algorithm yourself, or do you want a standard function from a standard library for some language?

Comment: For instance, in python, search for "powerset" on that page: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes and for C++, see this related question: [How to write C++ version of Python powerset function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898119/how-to-write-c-version-of-python-powerset-function)

Comment: A recursive formula for the powerset is:  `powerset(S u {a}) == {s u {a} for s in powerset(S)} u powerset(S)` where `u` means union, and S is a set that does not contain a (so that S u {a} has exactly one element more than S). You can use this recursive formula to write a function in your favourite language (using recursion or iteration).

Comment: @Stef why did you suggest recursive formula

Comment: Why would I not suggest it?

Comment: An equivalent formulation of that formula is: let a be an element of S; then `powerset(S) = { subsets that contain a } u { subsets that do not contain a }`

Comment: @Stef is for Dynamic programing?

Comment: There is no real need for dynamic programming here. A simple iterative or recursive function that repeatedly applies the formula will work.

Comment: @Stef just to be sure, I don't want to find powerset, I want powerset elements to intersect within themselves

Comment: In that case, please explain in more detail what you want. Also give an explicit example. If S = {a, b, c}, then what result do you want? So far, I can't understand what you mean. What are you intersecting with what?

Comment: @Stef added a picture

Comment: I don't unerstand the picture. Are you trying to build a graph?

Comment: @Stef no it's just lattice notation, S= {a,b ,c}--->1= intersect({}) ,2= intersect(a) , ........ , 5 = intersect( a,b ) , ............ 8 = intersect(a,b,c)

Comment: What does `intersect` mean in that context? Please give a very concrete example. What is `intersect(a)`?

Comment: Wait... Is that a geometry problem? Is the fact that your elements are called polygons relevant?

Comment: @Stef yes it is , it does not matter what it is , intersect( a, b,c )  = intersect( intersect ( a,b), c)

Comment: What do you mean in _'I want powerset elements to intersect within themselves'_...?

Comment: `i` is a set.  It is not a set of sets, so there doesn't seem to be any interpretation of `intersect(i)` that makes sense.

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes i is a set, this set has elements and at the end of day intersection( x € i)

Comment: how do you intersect a tetragon with a pentagon?

Comment: @MattTimmermans it is polytope, there is a polyhedron library

Comment: Oh... you want a *geometric* intersection, not a set intersection.  That's the kind of thing you want to make clear in the question :-)